# sbt gives me two scala-reflect jars

Tags: scala, classpath, sbt

After some dependency updates in a project, I somehow end up with `sbt clean update` leaving me *two* `scala-reflect` versions in `lib_managed`:

```
scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar
scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar
```

And consequently I get this lovely message when compiling:

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to term tools
[error] in package scala which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling 
        package.class.
```

sbt version is 0.13.0

How do I get rid of this problem?

---

I have the feeling, the following entry in the [sbt 0.13.0 Change Notes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html) is responsible:

> sbt no longer overrides the Scala version in dependencies. This allows independent configurations to depend on different Scala versions and treats Scala dependencies other than scala-library as normal dependencies. However, it can result in resolved versions other than scalaVersion for those other Scala libraries.

But it remains totally unclear to me what this implies and how one should handle this.

Comment: It isn't a bug for multiple versions of a library to be in lib_managed/, since it is just a project-local cache that provides more isolation from other projects on the same machine.  If you have multiple versions on a classpath, that would be a problem.  So, can you rephrase the problem in terms of classpaths?  It looks like you have the wrong version of scala-reflect on a classpath.  Information on that would help.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this problem again today in a different project. I can compile the project with sbt 0.12.4, but not 0.13.0; it fails with `"object tools is not a member of package scala"`. Mixed scala-reflect is now 2.10.1 versus 2.10.3.

Comment: That last problem is solved by using `exclude` to remove the second scala-reflect, and explicitly adding the scala-compiler again as dependency. It seems that 0.13 forgets about a transitive scala-compiler dependency.